# Can I back up a docker container volume data by just copying the data folder?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running Docker on Windows and I've used docker-compose to start a container which created a folder containing the following folders/files:

```
docker-compose.yml
data
|___conf
|    |__config.yaml
|
|___plugins
|___storage
```

I want to be able to back up the data that is stored in the container, I can see the data is being generated inside the `storage` directory. I've looked online and they say to back up volumes I would need to spin another container up and stop my current container etc... Can't I just write a script to back up that `storage` directory or better yet the entire `data` directory so that my data doesn't get lost?

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  verdaccio:
    image: verdaccio/verdaccio:4
    container_name: verdaccio
    environment:
        - VERDACCIO_PORT=4873
    ports:
        - "4873:4873"
    volumes:
        - "./data/storage:/verdaccio/storage"
        - "./data/conf:/verdaccio/conf"
        - "./data/plugins:/verdaccio/plugins"  
volumes:
    verdaccio:
        driver: local
```

Comment: Can you show us your `docker-compose.yml` and your `Dockerfile`s?

Comment: You will need some kind of volume setup.  If you use a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) then you can back up the corresponding host directory directly; if you use named volumes then there's a way to [mount them into another container for backup purposes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes).

Comment: @ThomasPr Added the `docker-compose.yml` file

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for that information, very helpful. Do you know what `docker-compose.yml` defaults too? bind-mount or volume?

Comment: It supports both syntaxes, there isn't a "default" _per se_.

Comment: From `docker-compose` documentation it looks like since I'm using `./data/....` it mounts a relative path on the host relative to the compose file. Doesn't mention bind or volume though...

Comment: You can always just back up the underlying path on your filesystem where the volume exists, i.e. /var/lib/docker/volumes/<volume>/_data/